# Write byte at a certain position on a binary file

Tags: java

How can I write something in a binary file, at a certain position, without having to copy the entire file, delete it and rewrite it with one value changed ?

I've tried with `FileOutputStream` but I can only append or truncate the file.

Comment: Is your intention to overwrite the value at the position or to insert a value at the position without altering the bytes that come thereafter? The later would likely require rewriting the rest of the file is it is stored contiguously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you can use a [Random access file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). You can set the position of the marker. Allowing you to choose where the next read or write occurs.